# What's the output of this code written in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
    int arr[ ] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   arr[i] = i;
} 
int res = arr[0] + arr[2];
System.out.println(res);
```

I'm a beginner in java, as you can see, and I'm not quite sure what's the output of this. Can someone answer and explain along the way?

Comment: Why don't you run the code to see?

Comment: if your beginner in java then first learn how to compile and execute java program then post your proper question here

Comment: I know how to compile and run my code in java, but I don't know why is the output 2. That's why I need an explanation, because I don't think the point is for me to run the code to see what's the output, instead of actually understanding why we got that output?

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @Solvex you should update your question and write output also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //if you're using Eclipse, press ctrl-shift-f to "beautify" your code and make it easier to read

    int arr[] = new int[3]; //create a new array containing 3 elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;//assign each successive value of i to an entry in the array
    }
    int res = arr[0] + arr[2];//add the 0th element value to the 2nd element value, save in res
    System.out.println(res);//print res, which is == 0 + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

basically what you are doing here is

```
int arr[ ] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   arr[i] = i; // you are adding elements on array location
} 
int res = arr[0] + arr[2];
System.out.println(res);
```

when first time loop execute `i` equals to  `0`, on location `0` you are assigning  `0` there and for `1,2` the same process is being applied. On line `int res = arr[0] + arr[2];` you are adding values of location `0 and 2` which are `0`and `2` so the output is `2` when you add `0+2 = 2` in basic mathematics

Answer (score 0):

1. On the first line, you are creating a new array of integers. The array has the elements arr[0], arr[1], and arr[2].
2. On the next three lines, is your for loop. As you have written in the loop, it will start from i=0 and will continue running while i < 3. Therefore, i will be 0, 1, and 2. In the loop itself, you are saying:
   arr[0] = 0, arr[1] = 1, arr[2] = 2.
3. On the last two lines, you have two statements. The first expression creates an integer called res. Then you are saying res = arr[0] + arr[2]. But as we just saw, in the for loop you made arr[0] = 0 and arr[2] = 2. Therefore, res = 0 + 2 = 2.
   On the last line you are just printing the result in the console.